# Como acessar o array em uma função extendida em Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Olá, estou fazendo uma extensão da classe `Array` onde eu quero criar um método que verifica se uma propriedade existe dentro do `Array`: assim:

```js
Array.prototype.contains = function(element){

    for(let e of this)
        if(e === element)
            return true;

    return false;

}
```

O problema é que não consigo acessar o objeto da instancia do Array ao utilizar esse método assim:

```
[1,2,3,4].contains(3); // deveria retornar true
```

o que preciso fazer para conseguir acessar a instancia do array nessa situação?

Comment: `console.log([1,2,3,4].contains(3));` está retornando `true`.

Comment: hm... né que arrumei na hora de escrever aqui sem querer? kkk

Comment: Parece que resolvi o problema ao redigitar o meu código aqui... a solução é a já descrita como o @Sam disse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso nem é resposta para o problema, que acabou não sendo um problema, mas vou recomendar não declarar prototype dessa forma, pois você vai acabar criando uma propriedade enumerada.

Tente fazer

```
for (let key in ['a', 'b', 'c']) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

Você irá receber 0, 1, 2 e "contains".

Para criar propriedades não enumeráveis, declare-as dessa forma:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'contains', {
    value: function(element) {
        for(let e of this)
            if(e === element)
                return true;

        return false;
    }
});
```

Também vou observar que JavaScript já possui um método "contains"

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].includes(3);
//true
```

Comment: hum, realmente não sabia do include muito menos dessa forma de declarar propriedades não enumeradas. muito obrigado pela resposta... com certeza começarei a usar essa forma de trabalho...